# CodeIgniter phpunit Ant build : CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: php, codeigniter, ant, phpunit

I'm new to Ant and so far I was able to successfully create the phplint task in the Ant build. Now I'm trying to integrate phpunit into ant build. phpunit is working on its own when I run the tests. But i get exception when i run it through the ant build.

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="php-automate-build-ant" default="full-build">

    <property name="phpunit" value="phpunit"/>

    <target name="composer" description="Install composer packages including require-dev.">
        <get src="https://getcomposer.org/download/1.2.1/composer.phar" dest="composer.phar"/>
        <exec executable="php" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="${basedir}/composer.phar"/>
            <arg value="install"/>
            <arg value="--prefer-dist"/>
            <arg value="--no-progress"/>
        </exec>
    </target>

    <target name="lint" unless="lint.done" description="Perform syntax check of PHP sourcecode files.">
        <apply executable="php" failonerror="true" taskname="lint">
            <arg value="-l"/>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/application">
                <include name="**/*.php"/>
                <exclude name="**/tests/**" />
                <!-- modified/ -->
            </fileset>
        </apply>
        <property name="lint.done" value="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="phpunit"
            unless="phpunit.done"
            description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
        <exec executable="${phpunit}" resultproperty="result.phpunit" taskname="phpunit">
            <arg value="--configuration"/>
            <arg path="${basedir}/application/tests/phpunit.xml"/>
        </exec>

        <property name="phpunit.done" value="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="full-build" depends="phpunit,-check-failure"
            description="Perform static analysis.">
        <echo message="Done"/>
    </target>

    <target name="-check-failure">
        <fail message="PHPUnit did not finish successfully">
            <condition>
                <not>
                    <equals arg1="${result.phpunit}" arg2="0"/>
                </not>
            </condition>
        </fail>
    </target>

</project>
```

Folder Structure

```
hocamose3
--application
----tests
------phpunit.xml
```

Exceptions

```
$ ant -v
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.1 compiled on February 2 2017
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: C:\xampp\htdocs\hocamose3\build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.8 in: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre
Detected OS: Windows 10
parsing buildfile C:\xampp\htdocs\hocamose3\build.xml with URI = file:/C:/xampp/htdocs/hocamose3/build.xml
Project base dir set to: C:\xampp\htdocs\hocamose3
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-ant-1.10.1-bin/apache-ant-1.10.1/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-ant-1.10.1-bin/apache-ant-1.10.1/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Build sequence for target(s) `full-build' is [phpunit, -check-failure, full-build]
Complete build sequence is [phpunit, -check-failure, full-build, composer, lint, ]

phpunit:
  [phpunit] Current OS is Windows 10
  [phpunit] Executing 'phpunit' with arguments:
  [phpunit] '--configuration'
  [phpunit] 'C:\xampp\htdocs\hocamose3\application\tests\phpunit.xml'
  [phpunit]
  [phpunit] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
  [phpunit] not part of the command.

BUILD FAILED
C:\xampp\htdocs\hocamose3\build.xml:31: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "phpunit" (in directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\hocamose3"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:426)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:440)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:629)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:670)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:496)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:857)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:287)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:113)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 24 more

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I followed the instructions in this link http://jenkins-php.org/automation.html

Comment: Can you confirm that `phpunit` exists in `C:\xampp\htdocs\hocamose3`?

Comment: I have installed phpunit as explained in this link https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html. i can run phpunit command in the cmd. phpunit is not C:\xampp\htdocs\hocamose3

Comment: If you added phpunit to your Windows PATH environment variable, I believe you will have to open a new terminal before the change will take effect.